# PHP call a url returning XML/JSON

Tags: php, xml

I am absolute beginner in PHP. Sorry for a very basic API question. I am stuck while coding at a point where I need to call a URL which will return me an XML or a JSON. Now I have to capture that in a variable.

For an example, I have written the following code:

```
class Search {
   private $documents = array();
   public function __construct() {
      $xmlDoc = new DOMDocument();
      $xmlDoc->load("solr.xml");
      .....
```

Now I am directly loading an XML. I dont want to do that, instead:

Step1: I want to call a http url which returns me an XML or JSON.
Step2: I need to store that in some variable like xmlDoc above
Step3: and later ofcourse I want to parse it.

I have no issues with step 3 but I just need some pointers or help as to how can I accomplish step 1 and 2?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`load` should accept a URL as a parameter.

```
$xmlDoc = new DOMDocument();
$xmlDoc->load('http://example.com/path/to/file.xml');
```

Or, you can use `file_get_contents` to download a URL to a string.

```
$xml = file_get_contents('http://example.com/path/to/file.xml');
$xmlDoc = new DOMDocument();
$xmlDoc->loadXML($xml);
```

Or for JSON:

```
$json = json_decode(file_get_contents('http://example.com/path/to/file.json'));
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Rocket!! Will this work on the fly, I mean I dont want to save XML file somewhere I just want to read the contents without IO i.e. whatever the URL returns

Comment: Yep it'll work on the fly.  You don't need to save it to a file on your drive.  It will download it to RAM.

Comment: @Rocket I think he actually wants to load it from a PHP page (see his Step 1). In that case load('http://example.com/xml.php?some_var=value') should do. The php page will read a database, create an XML file then display it, depending on the value of some_var.

Comment: @Ozzy: It doesn't matter where he wants to load it from (plus, he just said "from a url").  As long as the URL outputs the correct format, it can be whatever.

Comment: @chepe263: Why use `cURL` when `$xmlDoc->load('http://example.com/path/to/file.xml');` is one line? :-P

Answer (score 0):

For doing this with Json you first need a page which will have some json variables.

1. You can do this by yourself by typing:

   ```
   $jsonVar = array('var1','var2'); // several variables
   echo encode_json($jsonVar);
   ```
2. You can access these variables by typing:

   ```
   $jsonUrl = 'http://example.com/json.php';
   $jsonUrl = json_decode(file_get_contents($jsonUrl));
   ```
3. To display one of these variables you can type:

   ```
   echo $jsonUrl[1]; // you can use print_r($jsonUrl); //for displaying the right array numbers to access the vars
   ```